# Why do DNS zone files require NS records?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Say I've operating `ns1.example.org` and `ns2.example.org` on which I want to host the zone file for `example.com`

When I go to my registrar and purchase `example.com` , I will tell my registrar that my nameservers are `ns1.example.org` and `ns2.example.org`

My question then is, why do I then also need to specify those nameservers in the zone file for `example.com` ? Haven't I already told the .com nameservers where to lookup information on `example.com` , making the NS records redundant?

Clearly I'm missing some crucial fact...

Comment: For a more detailed discussion, check out: https://serverfault.com/questions/526278/clarification-of-why-dns-zone-files-require-ns-records#526322

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NS Records inside the zone are authoritative, the ones received from the registrar (the ones delegating the domain) are not, so if a server receives any difference from those records, the authoritatives win.
Also, servers listed in the NS record will receive a NOTIFY in case of zone changes (so the slaves can check for updates and so on).
One last thing, the RFCs [1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) and [1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) say that they must exist, so they must exist!

Comment: I wanted to post an answer exactly like that. But it came first.

Comment: Are there legitimate use cases for having the NS records not match the registrar's delegation?

Comment: @nathan Well you can have many NS records on your file, but some registrars will limit the number of name servers you can add on their interfaces. Now about having completely different records on the registrar and the zone file no I can't think on any right now.

Comment: Thanks - whats the big deal about "authoritatives winning"?Is it do with how recursive resolvers cache responses?i.e. does a  recursive resolver cache a more authoritative answer? Would someone explain the caching behavior of NS records from an Authoritative and Non Authoritative response. Say, a resolver receives delegation and caches delegation NS record from a parent; Next the resolver receives A record as answer from child - Does it also get / request NS record at the child authoritative Name server as part of response?