# Why would delegated nameservers ever be different to authoritative nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, delegation, authoritative

If you go on intodns.com and type in stackoverflow.com, the parent server tells me that nameservers for the domain are here:

```
ns1.serverfault.com.   ['198.252.206.80']   [TTL=172800] 
ns3.serverfault.com.   ['69.59.196.217']   [TTL=172800]  
ns4.serverfault.com.   ['69.59.196.122']   [TTL=172800] 
ns2.serverfault.com.   ['198.252.206.81']   [TTL=172800]
```

However, the zone file itself, which is authoritative, tells me that actually the nameservers are here instead:

```
ns2.serverfault.com  ['198.252.206.81']   [TTL=300] 
ns1.serverfault.com  ['198.252.206.80']   [TTL=300] 
ns3.serverfault.com  ['69.59.196.217']   [TTL=300]
```

Can any one explain why ns4.serverfault.com. would be listed as a nameserver when it isn't? What would happen if the resolver went to this address trying to find the A record for stackoverflow.com?

Comment: ns4.serverfault.com *is* authoritative for stackoverflow.com; that is, it responds to a query with the `aa` flag set. If it were not authoritative, it would either be responding based on data cached based on other queries (which requires the `aa` flag be cleared), with a redirection toward the root servers (usually `.`) or with a query refusal. You can [use dig as exemplified in my answer to your other question](http://serverfault.com/a/526322/58408) to see this for yourself. Try asking ns4.serverfault.com for www.example.net and observe the difference (just don't overdo it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever registered the domain name provided 4 nameservers to the registrar, so the registrar have added 4 glue NS records for the domain with the relevant addresses.

For some reason, which only stackoverflow will know, only 3 nameservers have been added to the zone file. While ideally the nameservers listed on a domain's registration (as visible in whois) should match what's in the zone file, these 2 lists come from different places and so it's possible for them to be different.

It appears that `ns4` does actually work so any requests going to that IP address will get a response.

Comment: Oddly enough, querying each of the four glue records for `serverfault.com NS` returns all four namesevers. I'm not sure why intodns would be reporting this. Assuming the SOA is accurate (yeah yeah I know), it was last updated on the 21st and the TTL is only 300.