# Role of Authoritative NS record in bind9 compared with Non-Authoritative NS record in Registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, ns-record

Whenever we register a new domain name from a Registrar, we need to tell them what is the nameserver by providing them the dns server IP address.

But in the same time in the **zone** file of our dns server (I will use bind9 in this case), we also add the RR like the following:

```
abc.net.    IN NS ns1.abc.net.
abc.net.    IN NS ns2.abc.net.
```

which is the authoritative record.

1)So what is the purpose of having the authoritative record of `NS` in the zone file of `abc.net`, since when one trying to resolve let say `www.abc.net`, the TLD `.net` already tell us they are in `ns1.abc.net` and `ns2.abc.net` ?

2)Since from the delegation concept point of view, `NS` record only need to be stored in the parent of the zone, meaning root server NS tell us NS of `.net`, `.net` server NS tell us the NS of `.abc.net` and `.abc.net` NS resolve the dns query. so in order to resolve `www.abc.net`, there are only 3 set of NS IP address we need to know:

1. root server NS that tell us where is `.net`, `.org`, `.uk`, `.it`...etc. root server NS IP is store in bind9 `named.ca`
2. `.net` NS that tell us where is `.abc.net`, `.xyz.net`, ...etc. `.net` NS IP is stored in root server NS record.
3. `.abc.net` NS that tell us where is `www.abc.net`, `mail.abc.net`,...etc. `.abc.net` NS IP is stored in `.net` NS record.
4. so since we don't have any `www.subdomain.abc.net`, we shouldn't need to store any NS record for `.subdomain.abc.net`, isn't it ?

3)What will happen if I don't put the `NS` record of `abc.net` in my `abc.net` zone file ?

4)What if I have `NS` record in my zone file but not in the Registrar? which one will be the resolver take ?

There are a detail [answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/526322/273982), but I still don't understand the meaning behind it.

Comment: Let me know if you're still having trouble after reading that. This one hurt my head for awhile too. :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Your answer in another thread is very clear ! But after reading yours, about my question(3) and (4), I am still not sure what is the correct answer. Do you mind to answer that for me ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: 3) The zone will refuse to load. Apex `NS` and `SOA` records are mandatory per the standards. 4) Without the registrar record, no one on the internet will be directed to your zone file. Only devices using this DNS server for recursion will receive answers from the zone file. This is not a recommended configuration as you do not actually own the zone.

Comment: (3) what if I have two dns server ns1 and ns2, I put them both in the Registrar, but only put ns1 in the zone file, will be the public use the ns2 if they do a 'dig www.abc.net' ? and if ns1 down, will public able to get any result ?

Comment: Initially both will be used, then only one will be used when the NS record is refreshed. (as described by the linked Q&A from earlier) One NS record is a very bad config.

Comment: I see, got it! Thanks for the reply ! and no worries, I definitely won't set only one NS record, it's just for the illustration of the scenario :)